# Is there a free solution to have a document library for .msg files with email attributes?

Tags: email

Looking to see if it's possible to copy bunch of msg files to a SharePoint subsite (not using site mailboxes app) and populate email attributes: From, Subject,Received, size

Comment: Hi! Can you please clarify he connection to SharePoint here? You mention Sharefile but I see no connection to any SharePoint technologies

Comment: Sorry I meant SharePoint not sharefile.

Answer (score 0):

If you email enable a document library, it can capture email messages and all that information is stored as metadata. If configured, you should see Incoming email options in the List Settings page for your document library. Create an alias and you should see emails flow into the library.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i'm not sure if this is the correct solution for my needs. I have an archive system that pulls emails out of exchange and stores them in a archived database. My backup solution then copies the files to a vault, i want to then copy the msgs from the vault to a Sharepoint site directory where i can retain the attributes. Can this be done?